# How to select one image from directory in PHP?

Tags: php

I know just image name I don't know image extension (jpg, gif, etc) (code auto select). Directory Name "Upload"

I have many images in upload folder like (Image1, Image2, Image3), but I want to select only one image `(image1 . (jpg)(gif)(png))`. Please give me PHP code for select image from directory with any extension.

```
    $img_detail = '11_detail'; // i wanna select this image
    $dir    = 'upload/advertisement/';
            $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach($files as $file){

            echo $file.'<br>';

            }
        // Code showing result like thi
//         11.swf
//         13.gif
//         14.gif
//         15.gif
//         16.jpg
//         16_detail.gif // i wanna select this image
//         index.php
```

All image extension not same

Comment: As you scan the dir and echo EVERY file that has been found its obvious you read every image in the browser. You have to check each file via Regex and echo only if regex match is true. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for details.

Comment: .. Or just use `glob`...

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy!

```
        $ad_id = '11';
        $addata = ad_data($conn, $ad_id, 'ad_img'); // Function

        $addetail = $ad_id.'_detail'; // this is my file name

        $dir    = 'upload/advertisement/';
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $file){

        $file = explode('.', $file);
        $currentname = current($file); // i have select current name
        $ext = end($file); // for final result 
    //  echo $firstname. '-'.$ext.'<br>'; // test
            if($currentname == $addetail){ // matching image name with required name
            $real_file = $currentname.'.'.$ext; // after matching use real extension 
            }
        }

        if(empty($real_file)){ // if file not found 
            echo $ad_id.'.'.$addata['ad_img'];
        }else{ // enjoy 
            echo $real_file;
        }
```